# Entity Framework Conditional join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created an MVC using Entity framework and I've encountered a situation which I don't know how to resolve.

I'm using the EF auto joins and relations (all my table models were created automatically by EF) .

Now for the problem - I have a table of customers, which has two(relavent) fields - `personID` and `employerID` . Only one of them contains data , the other will be null (a customer is either a person , or an employer) . When I try to include `employer` model in the result set, I'm getting thrown (without any message , when I debug I see that the content has data but the employeer is sometimes NULL) I'm also not sure about how the design should look like. This is my code :

Customer:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Account = new HashSet<Account>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int? EmployerId { get; set; }

    public Employer Employer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
```

Employer:

```
public partial class Employer
{
    public Employer()
    {
        Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? IdType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Person:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int IdType { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I'm running in my repository:

```
 var collectionBeforePaging = _context.Customer
```

Everything works, but Employer is NULL. If I use :

```
 var collectionBeforePaging = _context.Customer.Include(a => a.Employer)
```

Then the project fails .

How can I make this joins?

Answer (score 0):

Please define ForeignKey for Customer

```
public int? EmployerId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(EmployerId))]
public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you try to add `virtual` into all properties of object and list object? Are you using Lazy loading ?

Comment: I can try.. but why should they be virtual ?

Comment: With Entity Framework,the keywork 'virtual' is required to enable the proxy creation and lazy loading inside the DbContext object

Comment: It is really strange because without `virtual` and `include`, `Employer` will always be null

Answer (score 0):

What version of EF you use? I think you missing something like that :

In Employer :

```
[ForeignKey("EmployerId")]    
[InverseProperty("Customers")]
public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }

public int? EmployerId { get; set; }
```

In Customer :

```
[InverseProperty("Employer")]
public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

It can also be done in the Dbontext object